# How do I manipulate this CSV faster in bash?

Tags: bash, csv

I have a CSV data like this named `brands_url`

```
"relative/url","brand"
"relative/url1","brand"
```

I want to use the value of the second column brand to find a domain name of that brand by using this command line

```
curl url.json | jq -r '.[] | select(.slug=="brand") | .domain.production' # this would produce >> www.domain.com
```

And I want to use that result to prepend with the first column so the end result is going to be something like this.

```
"www.domain.com/relative/url"
"www.domain.com/relative/url1"
```

The problem with my script right now is it's very slow.

```
BRAND_JSON=$(curl url.json) 

while IFS= read -r line
do
  BRAND=$(echo $line | awk -F',' '{print $2}' | sed "s/\"//g")
  URI=$(echo $line | awk -F',' '{print $1}' | sed "s/\"//g")
  echo $BRAND
  DOMAIN=$(echo $BRAND_JSON | jq -r ".[] | select(.slug==\"$BRAND\") | .domain.production")
  echo $DOMAIN
  echo $URI
  echo "https://$DOMAIN/$URI" >> urls
done < "brand_urls"
```

The content of `$BRAND_JSON` looks like this

```
[{
  slug: "brand",
  ...,
  domain: {
     production: 'www.domain.com'
  }
 }, {
  slug: "brand1",
  ...,
  domain: {
     production: 'www.domain1.com'
 }]
```

Comment: that could probably be done with awk without explicitly reading each line.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that. Can you help?

Comment: can you share format of your $BRAND_JSON output ?. This could be done swiftly with awk

Comment: You are only spawning some `18` subshells, what do you expect?

Comment: @toy, yes, it can be done with just `jq` + `awk` in short way

Comment: The quotes in the CSV suggest you really need a proper CSV parser to handle fields that might contain commas. Standard shell tools don't count as proper CSV parsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can eliminate 80% of your subshell overhead simply by using *parameter expansion with substring removal*. You can replace 4 calls to `awk` and `sed` (and the subshell required for each `'|'`) simply by letting bash handle parsing the lines, e.g.

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
    BRAND=${line%\"}
    BRAND=${BRAND##*\"}
    URI=${line#\"}
    URI=${URI%%\"*}
    echo $BRAND
    DOMAIN=$(echo $BRAND_JSON | jq -r ".[] | select(.slug==\"$BRAND\") | \
    .domain.production")
    echo $DOMAIN
    echo $URI
    echo "https://$DOMAIN/$URI" >> urls
done < "brand_urls"
```

Give it a try and let me know. Much of the remaining time will be in the external retrieval of information by `curl`, bash cannot do anything about that.

Comment: current I have about 40,000 lines and it takes about 6 minutes. I'm guessing that's because of this line DOMAIN=$(echo $BRAND_JSON | jq -r ".[] | select(.slug==\"$BRAND\") | \
    .domain.production") that's slow?

Comment: Yes, there isn't anything bash can do there. The problem is the amount of time `curl` is taking to do the on-line lookup when you call `curl url.json`. If I were in your position, I would look at finding a faster way to get the on-line information you need. (I don't do much word getting pieces of information off the web, but I would check a smattering of tools like `whois` and other information tools and see if one can do what `curl` is doing faster.

Answer (score 1):

Short combination of **jq** + **awk** tools:

Sample `url.json` (should be valid json):

```
[
{
 "slug": "brand",
 "domain": {
    "production": "www.domain.com"
  }
}, 
{
 "slug": "brand1",
 "domain": {
    "production": "www.domain1.com"
 }
}
]
```

---

Sample `brands_urls.csv` content:

```
"relative/url","brand"
"relative/url1","brand1"
```

---

The job:

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{ gsub(/"/,""); a[$2]=$1;next }
         $2 in a{ printf "https://%s/%s\n",$1,a[$2] }' brands_urls.csv \
         FS='\t' <(jq -r '.[] | [.domain.production,.slug] | @tsv' url.json)
```

The output (backslash befor **\domain** is added intentionally cause SO does not allow to paste `www.domain.com` as code explicitely. The real output will be good):

```
https://www.\domain.com/relative/url
https://www.\domain1.com/relative/url1
```